# Ruby: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am learning Ruby on Rails, so I've created my first project and I got this error:

```
/Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle (fatal)
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller.rb:9:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/Work/2-Work/s-art-main/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/Work/2-Work/s-art-main/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/Work/2-Work/s-art-main/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/Anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Anton/Work/2-Work/s-art-main/bin/spring:13:in `require'
from /Users/Anton/Work/2-Work/s-art-main/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Can you please help me? I've googled tons of similar errors and still haven't found the right answer.

```
Rails 4.2.6
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your Ruby installation is mangled. Try reinstalling `debug_inspector`. `gem uninstall` and redo.

Comment: @tadman wow...thank you so much! Works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see an error relating to `.bundle` it's generally the case that your gem was compiled against a version of some shared library that's been updated or removed.

The normal fix for this is to uninstall and reinstall the offending gem. That will link it to the current version you have.